# Why does my python tkinter graphics not run outside pycharm when having connected it to mysql database

Tags: python, tkinter, mysql-connector

I developed a simple tkinter graphics which I connected it to mysql database. It works well whenever I run the file from pycharm, but outside pycharm my tkinter app will not run. If I then remove the import mysql statement and every mysql code from my app, it will run. Why?

Comment: The MySQL module is not installed in the Python environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, you made my day. I have resolved the issue.